# bnfc pretty printer java error

Tags: java, pretty-print, bnfc

I have this BNFC file describing a configuration file made of many sections where each section has a name between [] followed by a list of simple declaration

```
comment "#";
rulse Boolean ::= "True" | "False";
Conf. Config ::= [Section];  //a config is a list of sections
terminator Section "";

Sec. Section ::= "[" NomeSec "]" [Decl]; //A section is made of a name and a list of declarations
terminator Decl ";";

NomeSez. NomeSec ::= Ident;

Dec. Decl ::= VarN "=" Type;

VarName. VarN ::= Ident;

Int.    Type::=Integer;
Char.   Type::=Char;
String. Type::=String;
Float.  Type::=Double;
Bool.   Type::=Boolean;
```

Example:

```
[Section1]
Var1 = 3;
Var2 = "test";
#ignored comment

[SectionA]
var4 = True;
```

with an undefined  number of sections and declarations.

I ran the command `bnfc -m -java <filename>` from the shell and everything goes ok a part from the pretty printer. When its time to compile the prettyprinter.java tons of errors are generated. For example:

```
ES5/PrettyPrinter.java:10: error: reference to String is ambiguos 
private static final String _L_PAREN = new String("("); both class
ES5.Absyn.String  and class java.lang.String in java.lang match
```

All the errors are of this type. I'm wondering , i just built the grammar , i failed the grammar or the BNFC failed? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because BNFC creates java classes for each category and label, if use names that are in `java.lang` it creates ambiguities (e.g. `String`, `Boolean`...).

It works with the following renames (I also added an explicit entry point):

```
entrypoints Config;

comment "#";
rules MyBoolean ::= "True" | "False";
Conf. Config ::= [Section];  -- a config is a list of sections
terminator Section "";

Sec. Section ::= "[" NomeSec "]" [Decl]; -- A section is made of a name and a list of declarations
terminator Decl ";";

NomeSez. NomeSec ::= Ident;

Dec. Decl ::= VarN "=" Type;

VarName. VarN ::= Ident;

TInt.    Type::=Integer;
TChar.   Type::=Char;
TString. Type::=String;
TFloat.  Type::=Double;
TBool.   Type::=MyBoolean;
```

Comment: Thanks for help mate!